# ¿Alguna forma mas eficaz de insertar imágenes en componentes VueJs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

La forma mas habitual de insertar imágenes en VueJs (y en general) es usando el clásico:

```
<div class="post" v-for="post of posts" :key="post.id">
    <div class="post-user">
        <img src='@/assets/image.jpg' alt="">
        <div class="post-username">{{post.username}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">{{post.content}}</div>
</div>
```

Quiero hacer posts dinámicos. Ya saben, de estos que se añaden automáticamente al elemento post usando solamente objetos con propiedades en especifico. Estoy buscando la forma de añadir ese "@/assets/image.png" a los objetos post para luego hacer algo como:

`<img src="{{post.image}}">`

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto sin quedarse calvo?

Comment: ¿De donde sale ese array `posts`?¿Lo obtienes de una api, una base de datos o lo tienes hardcodeado en el script?

Comment: He puesto ese array en Vuex, y seguidamente le llamo desde mi componente usando un mapState, funciona correctamente hasta el momento

Comment: Muestra cómo añades un nuevo post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que tu imagen de tu post sea dinámica, solo debes guardar la URL de tu imagen en un attr (ejem: `image`) dentro de cada objeto `post` e invocarlo así:

```
<img :src="post.image" alt="">
```

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero la URL no me devuelve nada.

Empiezo a creer que podría ser porque esta llegando al :src como un string en lugar de una dirección, ¿Alguna idea de si tendrá algo que ver?

Comment: Probablemente el error este ahi, no te está devolviendo la URL de la imagen, checka que valor te trae en image

Comment: Ya lo logre, ¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Genial @SphiryeOrganizm 